# How to get the prefix of a string when pasted into a Jtextfield wherein I can insert only a limited number of characters

Tags: java, jtextfield, prefix

I am restricting a JTextField wherein I can only insert a certain number of characters into it and when it reaches its limit it emits a beep sound. (java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep()). It works perfectly fine when I type unto it. It works! But when I try to paste a long string unto it, it doesn't paste anything and I hear the beep sound instead. I want to get the prefix of the text instead of hearing the beep sound. Please help me! It looks like this.

```
public class LimitedPlainDocument extends javax.swing.text.PlainDocument {

    private int maxLen = -1;

    public LimitedPlainDocument(int maxLen) {
        this.maxLen = maxLen;
    }

public void insertString(int param, String str, javax.swing.text.AttributeSet attributeSet) throws javax.swing.text.BadLocationException {
if (str != null && maxLen > 0 && this.getLength() + str.length() > maxLen) {
            java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            return;
        }
        super.insertString(param, str, attributeSet);
    }

}
```

Comment: Define the term "prefix" for us.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I do this to limit the text field. textfield.setDocument(new LimitedPlainDocument(10)). So I can only insert a string with 10 characters only. But when I paste a text longer than 10. Example: "Kiira is beautiful" I'd like to get the "Kiira is b" instead of the beep sound.